# Authenticate Postfix through Dovecot with slightly different settings

Tags: postfix, ldap, dovecot

I'm setting up a server with Dovecot (2.2.2) and Postfix (3.1.0). Dovecot authenticates against LDAP and Postfix uses Dovecots SASL. That already works fine. But I would like to have slightly different LDAP settings for Dovecot and Postfix. Current setup:

```
passdb {
  driver = ldap
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-ldap.conf.ext
}
userdb {
  driver = ldap
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-ldap.conf.ext
}
```

Excerpt from `dovecot-ldap.conf.ext`:

```
user_filter = (& \
    (objectClass=gosaMailAccount) \
    (allowedServices=*I*) \
    (uid=%u) \
)
```

I wanted to have sparate LDAP filters (`allowedServices=*I*` for Dovecot and `allowedServices=*S*` for Postfix), to be able to disable SMTP and IMAP independently. Does anybody know a way to separate those settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an [answer on the Dovecot list](http://dovecot.markmail.org/search/?q=#query:%20page:1%20mid:t6blyauxlu5o3mqm%20state:results). I used the %s ([service variable](https://wiki.dovecot.org/Variables)) like this:

```
user_filter = (& \
    (objectClass=gosaMailAccount) \
    (allowedServices=*%L1s*) \
    (uid=%u) \
)
```

`%L1s` uses the first letter of the `%s` variable, which returns `imap` and `smtp` for the respective services.